# bootstrap carousel with menu, show active class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

might be a stupid questions, as I am a beginner:
This carousel can either slide automatically or via navigation. I've got 3 little problems with it:

1. when its sliding automatically, the navigation does not change the active list-element. I found this code, but I am not sure how to make this work or if there is any better solution:

   $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
     // do something…
   })
2. I want to change the active Item to be like on hover. I tried like `leistungenNav ul li a:active` but nothing worked. Do you know whats wrong in my code?
3. Out of some reason my media-query isn't working. I cannot understand why

   @media (min-width:600px;) {
       .leistungenNav li {
           float: left;
           border: 1px solid grey;
           width: 20%;
           text-align: center;
       }
   }

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lta9vra/

Comment: For media, change it to:

@media (max-width:600px) {
//...
}

Answer (score 3):

1. Your indicator `ul` needs to have the class `.carousel-indicators`. You'll have to style them so they're not dots any more though.
2. It's not `a:active` but `a.active` since `active` is a class, not a pseudo selector.
3. Drop the semicolon at the end of `@media (min-width:600px;)`.

Comment: If I add the '.carousel-indicators' it crashes my navigation, even if I try this:
 .carousel-indicators {
        all: unset;
    }

Comment: That's a painful problem with using bootstrap is that you have to **override** stuff a lot. What I did was going in `carousel-indicators`, as well as its `ul`, `li`, `a` and changed a lot of properties.

You can take a look at [this as a reference](https://jsfiddle.net/aarL0cwu/).